# How to grant access to the production branch from a customer server?

Tags: git, gitlab

I need deploy code by fetching the last commit in production branch from customers server.

How can I grand a machine to access a git repo in gitlab. As I see the access management is user-based not ssh key-based (expect for current user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a dedicated [GitLab deploy key](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html#deploy-keys) and provide that key to the machine.

If you enable that deploy key in a GitLab project (see the project settings), that machine will be able to read (not write to) that project.

Comment: Thanks VonC, Is it possible to grant them only to one branch?

Comment: No by default, you access a whole git repo